# Multiple working window worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have been hitting a wall of late, I made an incredible worksheet that the users interact with two windows. The bottom one the user insert data and the top one shows a history of the drugs a patient have taken.

As this takes data from multiple data sources it compiles the patient's history and must always be on the top window.

The problem:
I want a macro to activate a hidden sheet and activate it, but without change all the opened windows by doing so.
So I have 3 sheets, History, Search, Userdata ( not real sheet names )
the code: sheets("Search").activate changes both Excel windows with it.

I've tried to create to set the windows(2).activesheet("History") but an error is thrown as it only accepts an window object.

Then I tried the set and dim and a combination of those two functions but an error always happen.

Summary: How to change the active sheet in a single window when multiple excel windows are open

Comment: Are you trying to activate a sheet without the user seeing it (which I assume is the case because you say it is a hidden sheet), or are you trying to make the sheet visible (logically and physically)?

Comment: I unhide and select the sheet, but the problem is that both windows will change the activesheet.

Comment: You are going to have to include some code (the minimum amount to demonstrate the problem) within your question.  (Changing the active / visible sheet within a specific window should be as simply as activating that window and then activating the sheet you want to be visible in that window - it shouldn't be making it visible in both windows.)

Comment: And, just to be clear, your situation is that you have the "History" sheet visible in one window, and the "Userdata" sheet open in another window, and trying to `Activate` the "Search" sheet causes the "Search" sheet to be shown in both of the windows?

Comment: The code is simply: sheets("Search").activate
that will change the the window top and bottom window at once, and no, you can't manipulate an activesheet in a single window, at least I have not found how.

Comment: I created a workbook with three worksheets ("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"), generated two windows (so "Book1:1" and "Book1:2"), and then could happily do `Windows("Book1:1").Activate : Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate` and `Windows("Book1:2").Activate : Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate` which showed "Sheet1" and "Sheet3", then `Windows("Book1:1").Activate : Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate` to change it so that "Sheet2" was shown instead of "Sheet1", while "Sheet3" remained visible.  Please show some code so that we can see what is going wrong in your situation.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, I did not know about the two dots ":" to make the statement larger, since I have no way of knowing which  was the window the excel have chosen to be number one I could not reliably use the numbers, here is how it worked:

windows(1).activate: sheets("Search").activate

Make it a proper answer so I can thumb you up. Thanks!

Comment: The `:` is just a statement separator in VBA (to have two statements on one line instead of on separate lines).  I can't make my comment an "answer" because it doesn't explain why your `Activate` was changing both windows at once.